# Interactive sort over multiple groups in ssrs

Tags: reporting-services, reportingservices-2005

I have a report that is grouped by Region and then Office location.  The users would like the ability to sort on a date value.  I can get it to work for the innermost group (Office location).  However they want it to sort the whole table.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Add sorting to the table column.

1. Right click on the table column ->
   Properties
2. Click on Interactive Sort
3. Click "Add interactive sort"
4. For the Sort Expression, put "=Fields!COLUMN_NAME.Value"

Comment: Jon when I do that, it only sorts within the Office Location (inner most)group.  The users would like it to ignore the grouping and just sort.  Why they want the grouping and then the ability to over ride the grouping is beyond me.  Thanks for trying.

Comment: Kinda sounds like your going to have to make them compromise :)

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by using a **hidden** Chart placed outside the Groups.
Set as the following, for the column header that holds the interactive sort:

[image]

And for the chart:

[image]

At the Category Group, go to Properties, and remove any Sorting from there.

Answer (score 0):

Another simple way to solve this is to add two tablixs. One with the grouping, the other without.

Then you can add a "Group on X" boolean param and show and hide each tablix dependent on the users selection.

The best of both worlds and no need for two separate reports. The user can easily sort and export the entire dataset if required.